# Set up SSL-VPN in System Preferences

Tags: network, vpn

My company has a VPN network which staff are encouraged to connect to using an app called FortiClient. The VPN settings look fairly simple, and I would prefer to try use the inbuilt macOS interface to connect the VPN. I've tried a few various ways to no avail, does anyone have any luck?

Here are my FortiClient settings:
[image: FortiClient]

I notice that the "SSL-VPN" connection type isn't available in the System Preferences app. Otherwise I have been trying L2TP. Could this be the difference?

Is what I'm trying possible?

Comment: I don't think there is support for SSL VPN on the built-in client. L2TP is different, and won't work. I use tunnelblick with an SSL VPN.